# How to set a HTML cell style based on if the value in the cell is Yes or No using React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a table that is usng a sample dataset to populate.
I want to set the cell color based on what value is in the the cell.
I am not really too sure how to do that at this point.

**The CSS I want to use is here:**

```
.background-green  {
    background-color: #009000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.background-red  {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

**The sample data I am using is here:**

```
export const dataset = [
        { sampleid: "1", sample1: "No", sample2: "Yes", sample3: "No",  sample4: "Yes",  
          sample5: "Yes" },
        { sampleid: "2", sample1: "No", sample2: "Yes", sample3: "No",  sample4: "Yes", 
          sample5: "Yes" }
```

**The function used to populate the table is here:**

```
export function myTabledata() {
    return dataset.map(data=> (
        <tr>
            <td>{data.sampleid}</td>
            <td>{data.sample1}</td>
            <td className={'background-red'}>{data.sample2}</td>
            <td>{data.sample3}</td>
            <td>{data.sample4}</td>
            <td>{data.sample5}</td>
        </tr>           
       )            
    );
}
```

I did set one  tag to use the red CSS it does apply it however I am trying to understand to do it conditionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) like this:

```html
<td className={data.sample2 === 'Yes' ? 'background-green' : 'background-red'}>{data.sample2}</td>
```

If the condition is truthy (`data.sample2 === Yes`) `background-green` class will apply, otherwise (`data.sample2 === No`) `background-red` will apply.